# First cooling problem then buffle switch error

Tags: refrigerator, cooling

I have been waiting for my refrigerator do defrosting manually for the past 2 days. I have decided to do this because there was water leakage to the bottom section of the fridge and got an error saying "defrosting resistor (heating coil) or open fuse error". The pictures are below showing the condition of the freezer before manual defrosting.

After putting all the parts back and plugging all the sockets I noticed that the lighting of the bottom section do not work. I thought that I messed up with the sockets. Then I changed the places of 2 sockets with each other and one of the lights came on but the other one was blown. On the screen I saw the second error code about the buffle switch (probably something related with the part below called damper). The pictures of the device is below. Is there any way of testing it with multi-meter to see if it is damaged or not? I am also not familiar with the resistors so the resistor on the picture below is okay to have a dark color?

Damper - sscd.co.kr/bbs/content.php?co_id=en_02_02_07_01

[image: motorised buffle dumper /]
Also what is this part below? I have found this at the bottom section of the fridge. Can this part be measured? It looks like a thermometer and its socket has two pins on it.
[image: item]
P.S: Cannot post other picture because of reputation problem!(additional pictures are in the comments section)

Comment: Upload any additional pics to imgur.com and post links.  Someone will add them to the question for you .

Comment: @Tyson I cannot add links, system does not allow me, so where can i add links?

Comment: Just upload to imgur.com, you do not even need to create an account to do that. Put think links right here in comments and someone with more rep will add to your question.

Comment: (1) http://imgur.com/mj6eQM9
(2) http://imgur.com/0FUCyfG
(3) http://imgur.com/Ct8rSyF

Comment: (4) http://imgur.com/suf98Lk (5) http://imgur.com/suf98Lk (6) http://imgur.com/t6JggCJ